# What is the space-time complexity of the scan operator in APL?

Tags: time-complexity, apl, dyalog

Typically `scan`, both left and right variants, are O(n) in both space and time. However it seems that APL's `\` operator is like `scanl` but seems to behave differently in that it is right associative and runs over the array each time, making it O(n^2).

For example,

```
nums ← 10?10  ⍝ 1 7 4 5 10 3 9 6 2 8
⌈\nums        ⍝ 1 7 7 7 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

gives me the correct behavior but by right associativity is equivalent to

```
(1 f (7 f (4 f (5 f (10 f (3 f (9 f (6 f (2 f 8)))))))))     ⍝ where f ← (⊣,⌈)
```

so the last operation is `1 f (7 7 7 10 10 10 10 10 10)`

Isn't this inefficient, what is the actual big O complexity here and/or is there some idiomatic optimization?

Comment: yeah apl scan sucks but you can roll your own with https://aplcart.info/?q=scanl#

Comment: not only that but it seems to give wrong answers when order matters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273199/what-is-the-correct-approach-to-efficiently-perform-a-scanl-in-apl

Comment: it's not 'wrong' it's just not the regular order

Comment: Well if doesn't behave like a scanl should I would call that wrong. I guess you could argue that it's not technically a scanl, but it's confusing coming from Haskell etc to call it scan

Comment: yeah, it's definitely confusing, and it probably is 'wrong' but it's by choice

Answer (score 1):

You are right in your algorithmic description Scan, and in the general case, it is indeed O(N²). However, by far the most common uses of it is with a known set of scalar primitives (including `+`, `∨`, `∧`, `⌈`, `⌊`, `<`, `≤`, `≠`). These are recognised by the interpreter,  which then uses special code O(n) (or less, as they might leave early) code.

We can easily demonstrate this by comparing the performance of `+` with the functionally identical `+∘⊢` (plus, where the right argument is pre-processed by the identity function):

```
      'cmpx'⎕CY'dfns'
      a←?2000⍴127
      cmpx'+∘⊢\a'
1.8E¯1
      a←?4000⍴127
      cmpx'+∘⊢\a'
7.6E¯1
```

We can see that `+∘⊢\` took about 4 times as long (0.2 s → 0.8 s) when we doubled the number of small integers from 2000 to 4000. Whereas:

```
      a←?2000⍴127
      cmpx'+\a'
1.5E¯6
      a←?4000⍴127
      cmpx'+\a'
2.9E¯6
```

`+\` only doubles (15 ms → 29 ms) when going from 2000 to 4000 small integers. Also note the extreme performance difference between the optimised case and the non-optimised case.

Scan gets its order of evaluation from Reduce. [Iverson](https://apl.wiki/Ken_Iverson) explains in *[Conventions Governing Order of Evaluation](https://www.jsoftware.com/papers/EvalOrder.htm)*:

> 4. In the definition
>
>    ```
>       F/x ≡ x1 F x2 F x3 F ... F x⍴x
>    ```
>
>    the right-to-left convention leads to a more useful definition for nonassociative functions F than does the left-to-right convention. For example, `-/x` denotes the alternating sum of the components of `x` , whereas in a left-to-right convention it would denote the first component minus the sum of the remaining components. Thus if `d` is the vector of decimal digits representing the number `n` , then the value of the expression `0=9|+/d` determines the divisibility of `n` by `9` ; in the right-to-left convention, the similar expression `0=11|-/d` determines divisibility by `11` .

Comment: I have a follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273199/what-is-the-correct-approach-to-efficiently-perform-a-scanl-in-apl