# What is the correct approach to efficiently perform a scanl in APL?

Tags: operator-precedence, apl, dyalog

Following from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272288/what-is-the-space-time-complexity-of-the-scan-operator-in-apl), it seems that APL performs a scanl in O(n^2) but the compiler is smart enough to optimize for simple primitives. What then is the best strategy to apply `\` to non-simple functions? Additionally, there are many cases when the right associativity **does** affect the result, for example:

```
{0⌈⍺+⍵} \ 3 ¯4 1 5 ¯1 ¯2 ¯3 2 0 4           ⍝ 3 0 3 5 4 5 5 5 5 5
```

Which is not the answer I would have expected `3 0 1 6 5 3 0 2 2 6`

Comment: You might want to state the result you expect. `3 0 1 6 5 3 0 2 2 6`?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on one possible solution, but don't know if it's the most idiomatic.

```
s←0 ⋄ ↑{s⊢←0⌈s+⍵}¨ 3 ¯4 1 5 ¯1 ¯2 ¯3 2 0 4
```

Correctly gives me `3 0 1 6 5 3 0 2 2 6`